# Type Script : SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: class, typescript, runtime-error, unexpected-token

I am trying to Implement this simple typescript code. But having weird error while running through node command. Can someone please help?

Main.ts

```
class Wedding {

    bond:string;
    money:number;

    isWeddingPossible() {
        if(this.bond === 'Strong' && this.money > 10000  ){
            console.log('Wedding can be done.');
        }
        else{
            console.log("Go to hell");
        }
    }
}

let wedding = new Wedding(); 
wedding.bond = 'Not Strong'; 
wedding.money = 500; 
wedding.isWeddingPossible();
```

Run commands : tsc main.ts && node main.ts

Error :

```
/ts-hello/main.ts:3
    bond:string;
        ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Comment: if you want to run main.ts right away you have to use npm package ts-node instead, eg. "ts-node main.ts"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should run `node main.js` instead of `main.ts`. You compile your `.ts` file and it creates it's `.js` file. So you need to run that compiled `.js` file via node.